How to decode packet length from variable number of bytes?
I am intercepting data from one application, it accepts binary data in the form of packets of information. At the beginning of each packet, depending on the length of the packet, there are 1, 2 or 3 bytes containing the length of the packet. But the length is encoded, as for a short packet it is 1 byte stating, for longer ones 2 or 3 bytes. The packet length also includes the number of bytes in which the length is encoded
Example packets:

1a0420ee26ee2622..., actual packet length is 23 bytes, 0x1A - is packet length
2e0220b8218fbd07..., actual packet length 43 bytes, 0x2E - is packet length
ac060014ec0f9700..., actual packet length 810 bytes, 0xAC06 - is packet length
af0c0014ca4f9702..., actual packet length 1581 bytes, 0xAF0C - is packet length
eb080014a46f9700..., actual packet length 2399 bytes, 0xEB08 - is packet length
ff08021734c52b00..., actual packet length 2796 bytes, 0xFF08 or 0xFF0802 - is packet length

During my brainstorming I was able to determine that for packets 1 and 2 the length is obtained
byteArr[0] - 3

// For 1a0420ee26ee2622... it's 1a => 26 - 3 = 23 bytes

for 3 and 4 the length is obtained by the formula
(byteArr[1] << 7) + (byteArr[0] & 127) - 2

// For ac060014ec0f9700... it's (0x06 << 7) + (0xAC & 127) - 2 = 810 bytes

I could not understand 5 and 6, as well as the magic subtraction of -3 and -2.
I'm trying to figure out how to decode the packet length field in order to be able to process them. The server often sends multiple concatenated data packets in one response, and the only way to separate them is to decode their size.
Maybe there is some algorithm for such a length record?
Maybe someone has encountered something like this and knows these encoding rules?
EDIT:
I found this algorithm, it's LEB128.

You don’t have a specification?

Can you add header format, payload format, any other metadata?

Specification by example is plain awful. How do you know 1. to 6.? Please identify/describe application as well as information.

I don't have any specification, the app is not created by me, the app is an online game, and I'm trying to figure out the data exchange format on my own.

@greybeard I figured it out on my own by researching hundreds of data packets
